# HttpActionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization is null

Tags: c#, rest, iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc 4 rest and write my own basec authentification logic.

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        else
        {
            //do staff here
        }
    }
```

It works on local iis. But it does not work on producation station. I always get null. I set basic authentification enabled on IIS. I am testing with Fiddler and my request looks like that:

```
User-Agent: darwin/1.0 CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.0.0
Authorization: Basic cmFkaWt2b3N0b2tAZ21haWwuY65tJjE6QkFBREVEcHlQYmtjQkFOcXh4UmFrdG1JMUJ2bjBPYXVQVk9NcnFZMEg4V3BhakljSlk2WkJMTWtra1FIWHFrcEZmdEkyNmFEZEppYWlKVVZJOTZpUGJuMzRMc1luemJHM2FPV3paQk5DTG1Xak9FZGU3YTdGWVhVem1QeTlEWkM4cW02YWZoWkJGWkIzbGFXMTNaQjlKdQ==
Content-Length: 10128
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 192.168.7.4
```

Does anybody know why it happens?

Comment: I had the same problem, and for me, I had incorrect Authentication-settings set for the "Web Site" in IIS. Anonymous Authentication must be enabled.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, implement `OnAuthorization()` instead of `OnActionExecuting()`.  `OnAuthorization()` is executed prior to `OnActionExecuting()`. It's important to check for authorization even before the user reaches `OnActionExecuting()` codes.

But **your answer**: the most possible situation is that the `<authentication>` is set to "None" in production *web.config* file. Change it as follows and you'll be all set:

```
<authentication mode="Forms"/>
```